# Return binary result from phantomjs webserver

Tags: javascript, base64, mime-types, phantomjs

Is there any way to return result froma PhantomJS webserver as binary?

To be more specific, If I render a screenshot of a page as base64, can I then transform this base64 string into binary and return it so the client receives it as an image?

This is what I have so far, I've commented out some of my experiments which apparently doesnt work

```
response.statusCode = 200;
response.setHeader("Content-Type", "image/png");
//response.setHeader("Content-Encoding","base64");
var base64 = page.renderBase64('png');
//var binary=atob(base64,"b");
response.write(base64  );
response.close();
```

Ideas?

Comment: Have you got any progress on the issue?

Answer (score 6):

You can just set the Encoding to binary, and it will work:

```
response.statusCode = 200;
response.headers = {
    'Cache': 'no-cache',
    'Content-Type': 'image/png'
};
response.setEncoding('binary');
response.write(atob(page.renderBase64('png')));
response.close();
```

Comment: What the hell is `atob`?

Comment: @devius its to decode BASE64 data: [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowBase64) [w3c](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/webappapis.html#dom-windowbase64-atob)

Comment: Just stumbled onto this: binary encoding is broken in current PhantomJS-release (https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/13026)

Comment: U could still use older version, or try to compile your own. U can run old version just with binary encoding scripts, right?

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to use [binary encoding](http://phantomjs.org/api/webserver/) in webserver module and [page.evaluate](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/method/evaluate.html) inside web page module to generate binary content.

the result is something like this (assuming *page* is defined) :

```
response.statusCode = 200;
response.setEncoding("binary");
response.setHeader("Content-Type", "image/png");
var base64 = page.renderBase64('png');
var binary = page.evaluate(function (data) { return atob(data, "b");}, base64);
response.write(binary)
response.close();
```

Comment: Its absolutly unnecessary to use page.evaluate! Its just slower!

Comment: I've set content type too to the webserver examples so I can compare phantomjs screenshots and rendered code agains my live firefox rendering it's parsed output. Webserver is so cool.
Also u can automate both tests using Selenium and UnitTest, as example.